# page number in a diamond box

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I have the following code I need to put the page number at the top of the page resulted in a diamond box. I would be grateful for any help or if you can indicate to me the code to generate it.

[image]

There is something I forgot, the page number should be on the left for the even pages and on the right for the odd pages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Where is your code? Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Should the position alternate from left to right in even and odd-numbered pages or should it always be to the left?

Comment: I dont have any code.  I want you give me the code see the picture

Comment: alternate from left to right .odd number at left.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option using the [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) and [`tikzpagenodes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) packages:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[OC]{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[diamond,draw,font=\small\itshape] at (current page header area.south west) (dia) {\thepage};
\draw[double=white] (dia.east) -- (current page header area.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\fancyhead[EC]{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[diamond,draw,font=\small\itshape] at (current page header area.south east) (dia) {\thepage};
\draw[double=white] (dia.west) -- (current page header area.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\fancyhead[OR]{\small\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[EL]{\small\nouppercase\rightmark}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Test section}
\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the horizontal rules are not to be of the same width:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[OC]{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[diamond,draw,font=\small\itshape] at (current page header area.south west) (dia) {\thepage};
\draw (dia.3) -- (current page header area.south east|-dia.3);
\draw (dia.357) -- ([xshift=-7pt]current page header area.south east|-dia.357);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\fancyhead[EC]{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[diamond,draw,font=\small\itshape] at (current page header area.south east) (dia) {\thepage};
\draw (dia.177) -- (current page header area.south west|-dia.177);
\draw (dia.183) -- ([xshift=7pt]current page header area.south west|-dia.183);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\fancyhead[OR]{\small\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[EL]{\small\nouppercase\rightmark}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Test section}
\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: there is something i forgot . in the even pages at left be chapter's name .and in odd pages at right , season's .thank you for code

Comment: @user32944 please see my updated answer. Don't forget (noe that you've received some answers) that you can accept the one you consider best solved your problem by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 4):

Borrowing from Gonzalo Medina's solution, but making it free of tikz, and with the double line of different lengths:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[OC]{%
  \def\stackalignment{c}%
  \topinset{\itshape\thepage}{\scalebox{5}{\(\diamond\)}}{1.5ex}{}%
  \rule{-.2ex}{0ex}%
  \def\stackalignment{l}%
  \stackon[1pt]{\rule[2.8ex]{2.5in}{.1ex}}{\rule{2.55in}{.1ex}}}
\fancyhead[EC]{%
  \def\stackalignment{r}%
  \stackon[1pt]{\rule[2.8ex]{2.5in}{.1ex}}{\rule{2.55in}{.1ex}}%
  \rule{-.2ex}{0ex}%
  \def\stackalignment{c}%
  \topinset{\itshape\thepage}{\scalebox{5}{\(\diamond\)}}{1.5ex}{}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

and for even pages:

[image]