# Making a bullet journal notebook using latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, book-design, notes

I want to make a bullet journal notebook using latex. indeed I want to find a way to turn the idea described in the [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135405/print-a-notebook-with-latex) into a bullet journal notebook. For a bullet journal notebook, I need a dotted notebook whose papers are numbered at the bottoms. I only can make a dotted paper using the following code

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[letterpaper,hmargin={0mm,0mm},vmargin={3mm,3mm}]{geometry}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
    \foreach \x in {0,...,41}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,54}
    {
        \fill[black!65] (\x,\y) circle (0.06cm);
    }       
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In other words, I want to change the papers of the notebook described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135405/print-a-notebook-with-latex) with a dotted paper as I explained using the code mentioned above. Furthermore, I need to add some titles to some specific pages such as index, futurelog, and so on.

I don't know how to combine these ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a starting point.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\IfFileExists{lattice.pdf}{
    \tikz{
        \foreach\x in{.5,1,...,8}{
            \clip(0,0)rectangle(8.5in,11in);
            \node[above right]{\includegraphics[page=2]{lattice.pdf}};
            \draw(8in,10.5in)node[circle,draw,fill=white]{page 1};
        }
    }
    \tikz{
        \foreach\x in{.5,1,...,8}{
            \clip(0,0)rectangle(8.5in,11in);
            \node[above right]{\includegraphics[page=2]{lattice.pdf}};
            \draw(.5in,10.5in)node[rectangle,draw=red,fill=white]{page 2};
        }
    }
    \foreach\page in{3,...,10}{
        \tikz{
            \clip(0,0)rectangle(8.5in,11in);
            \draw(4.25in,\page in)node{Algorithmically generate your pages};
            \foreach\t in{1,...,\page}{
                \foreach\s in{1,...,\t}{
                    \draw[shift={(4.25in,5.5in)}](\t*360/\page:5)--(\s*360/\page:5);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
{
    \tikz{
        \clip(0,0)rectangle(8.5in,11in);
        \draw(4.25in,5.5in)node{
            Rename the current PDF file as \texttt{lattice.pdf} and compile again.
        };
    }
    \tikz{
        \foreach\x in{.5,1,...,8}{
            \clip(0,0)rectangle(8.5in,11in);% declare paper size
            \draw[dash pattern=on0off.5in,line cap=round,line width=2pt]
                (\x in,.5in)--(\x in,10.5in);% Le dots
        }
    }
}

\end{document}
```